# Telerik gridview to check for row dirty

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgridview

How can we know if a row is dirty in a telerik gridview?
In datagridview we had IsCurrentRowDirty property.
Is there any such property in Telerik?

Comment: Have you considered tracking this in the bound dataitem instead? A lot of business apps will track object "dirtiness" in the business layer rather than expecting the grid to do it. This is part of the separation of concern that MVVM provides

Comment: Charleh this would require me to compare each property of the object before and after changes. Winforms datagridview provided a ready made property of IsCurrentRowdirty to do that

Comment: Not necessarily - you could just track when properties changed on the object via getter/setter methods and flag `IsDirty` when changes are made. Obviously this doesn't support n-level undo or know when a value is changed back to the original value - but it depends how complex you want your property tracking. Most business object frameworks contain this functionality (as well as ORMs that track object state for you if you don't need a deep business layer). The bottom line is, I don't think this property is there because it's not the grids duty to track changes

Comment: Look here for some info if you want to roll this yourself. You could create a base class which your objects inherit from which encapsulates this functionality and then access it via property getter/setters: http://paulstovell.com/blog/editable-object-adapter

Comment: Thanks a lot Cherleh. This was pretty informative. I did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this with RadGridView is to use the CellValueChanged event:

```
void radGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Tag = "ThisRowIsDirty";
}
```